# Mail.app repeatedly loses IMAP credentials

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave, email

Recently Mail.app on my laptop cannot connect to Gmail IMAP accounts.  It says **Login Failed** in the status bar, and no amount of refreshing will make it work.  If I quit and relaunch Mail then it authenticates and downloads new messages, but then after a few minutes it fails again.

This problem happens on both of my laptops, which I guess makes sense because they share the same iCloud account.  I have tried removing the account from System Prefs > Internet Accounts and then re-adding it.  This works for a few minutes but then the problem comes right back.  My iOS devices which also share the iCloud account don't have any problems.
Log file is below, with tokens and IPs redacted.  This is happening on Mojave 10.14.4.  I have two Gmail IMAP accounts, and the same problem happens with both, which makes me think the problem is with the application.

```
INITIATING CONNECTION May 12 12:51:40.605 host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x0 -- thread:0x600001f59d80

CONNECTED May 12 12:51:41.174 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80

READ May 12 12:51:41.175 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
* OK Gimap ready for requests from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

WROTE May 12 12:51:41.175 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
1.323 CAPABILITY

READ May 12 12:51:41.305 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
1.323 OK Thats all she wrote! xxxxxxxxxxx

WROTE May 12 12:51:41.305 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
2.323 ID ("name" "Mac OS X Mail" "version" "12.4 (3445.104.8)" "os" "Mac OS X" "os-version" "10.14.4 (18E226)" "vendor" "Apple Inc.")

READ May 12 12:51:41.343 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
* ID ("name" "GImap" "vendor" "Google, Inc." "support-url" "http://support.google.com/mail" "remote-host" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "connection-token" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
2.323 OK Success xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

WROTE May 12 12:51:41.347 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
5.323 AUTHENTICATE OAUTHBEARER xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

READ May 12 12:51:41.496 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

WROTE May 12 12:51:41.496 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
AQ==

READ May 12 12:51:41.646 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.gmail.com -- port:993 -- socket:0x600002002d00 -- thread:0x600001f59d80
5.323 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Comment: I do have exactly the same issue. Have you found solution?

Comment: This problem seemed to go away after updating to 10.14.6